# Extending a hypersurface to a foliation

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, foliations

Given a smooth embedded submanifold of codimension 1, i.e. it is a hypersurface, say $H \hookrightarrow M$, is it possible to show that there exists an open nbd. $U\supset H$ in $M$ s.t it is diffeomorphic to $H \times (-a,a)$ for some $a\in \mathbb R$?
Note 1. If needed, assume orientability of $H$; it seems that one might need a non-zero section of the normal bundle.
Note 2. A proof without the use of a riemannian metric is appreciated.

Comment: Immersed is not enough (think of a figure $8$ in the plane, or a spiral accumulating on a circle), but modulo details, if $H$ is embedded, equip $M$ with a smooth Riemannian metric and consider the distance spheres, each locally a $2$-sheeted cover of $H$, and that together foliate a neighborhood of $H$.

Comment: The figure 8 is not a submanifold, right? By immersed submanifold, I mean an injective immersion. Can you please expand a bit more?

Comment: The $8$ is not a manifold, as you say, but it _is_ the image of an immersion on the circle, and I wasn't sure what definition you had for "immersed submanifold". :) In case it matters, there are injective immersions such as an [irrational winding on a torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_flow_on_the_torus); whether or not that example "works" depends on the precise definition of "locally diffeomorphic to $H \times (-a, a)$.

Comment: I mean local diffeomorphism in the following sense: M,N manifolds, with U,V open subsets of M,N respectively. By local diffeomorphism, I refer to the diffeomorphism from U to V.